# Getting linkedin OAuth cookie to the back end

Tags: jquery, api, cookies, groovy, linkedin-api

So my current issue is that I am trying to allow users to login with the JS linkedin API and I need to take the OAuth cookie passed by the linkedin API and store it on the back end.

I can see the cookie's contents in firebug and they look something like this:

```
{
     "signature_method":"HMAC-SHA1",
     "signature_order": ["access_token", "member_id"],
     "access_token":"AD2dpVe1tOclAsNYsCri4nOatfstw7ZnMzWP",
     "signature":"73f948524c6d1c07b5c554f6fc62d824eac68fee",
     "member_id":"vvUNSej47H"
     "signature_version": 1
}
```

But in my JQuery I am trying to pass this to the back end using the JQuery cookie plugin command

```
//I starred out my key here but it corresponds 
//to the cookie name I see in firebug.
var cookie = $.cookie(linkedin_oauth_*****);
```

So I am pretty stumped as to why I am not able to access this cookie and get the data to my back end groovy controller. Am I going about this the correct way and just accessing the cookie wrong or is there an easier way to do it without adding in a lot of extra code and overhead?

Comment: is the cookie marked `HttpOnly`? that would prevent it from being available to the client-side script: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the JS tokens to make REST-based calls. The JS API is based on OAuth2, while the REST API still uses Oauth1.

However, you can exchange the JSAPI token for a REST API token. See here: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I've seen that "Exange JSAPI token" page before, but it's not working at the moment.

I don't have a `linkedin_oauth_${clientId}` cookie - I do have a `linkedin_oauth_${clientId}_crc` cookie, but it's `null`.

I've figured out that I can send `IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token` to my back-end and send a request to https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json with the `oauth_token` header set and I get a valid response.